# How can I move Ubuntu from one partition to another?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, gparted

I have installed Ubuntu on a small partition and its size is 60GB, and now I want to move it to a bigger partition.

[image: this is a photo of my hard disk partitions]

I want my system  to be at `partition 6` without losing my data, 
and if i can merge `partition 5 and 6` at the same time.

 knowing that `partition 3` is for windows 10 , and also I don't wont to lose it.

Comment: I typically suggest you install / (root) into 25 or 30GB if using separte /home and/or data partitions. You cannot merge partitions, but would have to fully backup data and delete one or the other and restore data to larger. Mount your NTFS partition and then Post this: `df -h`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu: Copy Partition 6 data to external drive. Delete Partition 6 from HDD using GParted. Stretch Partition 5 to fill empty space using GParted. Copy Partition 6 data from external drive back to Partition 5 on HDD. If Partition 6 contains a home directory use Rsync to copy.

Comment: @oldfred can you give me details or usefull link?

Comment: Need the df output to know how much space you have. Are you looking for backup info? But /home is normally a lot larger than / (root). I prefer to keep /home inside / but have all data on data partition. My 20.04 is 8.3GB used and both my 16.04 & 18.04 grew to about 12GB after 2 years. But I regularly houseclean. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk